# There is something wrong with my indentation but what is the right way?

Tags: python, indentation

When I double click on the file to run it, it just pops up for a few seconds and disappears. I've been told it is a problem with my indentation but what exactly. I'm new to program, so a solution on how to fix my indentation would be helpful.

```
import random
print('I am thinking of a number between 1 and 50')

number = random.randint(1, 50)
guess = int(input('Can you guess what it is: '))

while guess != number:
    if guess > number:
        print('Lower...')
    else:
        print('higher...')

guess = int(input('Can you guess what it is: '))


print('Correct!')

input('\n\nEnter.')
```

Comment: Can you not run it by running python filename.py?

Comment: This is duplicate question from the same author

Comment: If you're on Windows, you may need to use `py -3` instead of `python`: http://docs.python.org/3.3/using/windows.html#launcher

Answer (score 2):

You shouldn't need to click on the filename.py file. Just run

```
ipython filename.py
```

in terminal. I tried this and saw a logic error with your guess statement.

Or just

```
python filename.py
```

if you don't have ipython installed.

**Update**:

It looks like you may be having issues with your path and running python.

Windows: [resource1](https://code.google.com/p/tryton/wiki/AddingPythonToWindowsPath)
Mac: [resource2](http://docs.python.org/2/using/mac.html)

Comment: Not everyone is using ipython

Comment: @JimmyKane I've added python for more diverse answer. Thank you.

Comment: It says 'python' is not recognized as an internal or external command.

Comment: That means it isn't installed on your path.

Comment: @Pippin It won't output anything if it isn't recognized as a command.

Comment: @sweeneyrod is right. Sounds like it could be a path issue. Have you been able to run python files before? I've added a resource for windows and OSX to my answer that goes over fixing paths.

Comment: If it's Python 3.3 on Windows, the command may be `py -3` (Python 3.3 uses `py.exe` and takes the version as a command line parameter to better accommodate multiple versions)

Comment: Thanks but once I get to enviromental variables what do I do then?

Comment: I've been able to run all my other python files perfectly by saving them on to my desktop then double clicking on them.

Comment: @user3052934 Have you seen this [page](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3701646/how-to-add-to-the-pythonpath-in-windows-7). It links to [this](http://patheditor2.codeplex.com/) path editor.

Answer (score 0):

Run it though terminal. Check @pipins answer.

This way you'll see the output and any errors about indentation etc and where they where made.

As I see there is no problem with your identation

Answer (score 0):

You should take a close look at the line `guess = int(input('Can you guess what it is: '))` and think about the intended logic of the while loop...

(the indentation seems to be formally correct, but of yourse your program does behave as you expect...)

The tipp "indentation" is correct, but misleading as well. Since your program seems to do something, your python settings should be ok (but it would not hurt to add python to your system path).
The reason your programm closes nearly instantly **is due to a wrong indentation** which results in a wrong execution logic.

It would be best to follow your program execution in a debugger or to insert several print statements.

In fact, you don't have to change much ;).

Comment: Extended my answer a bit - several discussion threads here are quite misleading...

Answer (score 0):

### This does not require adding python to your path

open console and type:

```
/path/to/python.exe /path/to/<file>.py
```

As an example:

```
C:\Python27\python.exe C:\Users\user\Desktop\my_program.py
```

### Explaination:

If you double click the .py file, the console opens and *should* wait for user input.

However, **if there are errors** it will close immediately and you won't be able to view those errors.

Running your program from the console directly ensures the console remains open and will allow you to see the errors.

Comment: It says 'python' is not recognized as an external or internal command.

Comment: System variables or User variables?

Comment: Just add it to system variables in the 'Path' section

Comment: Just added directions to do this without adding it to your path, but in the long term it's not as convenient.

Comment: Thank you. It has finally worked.